# Como especificar diretório onde o bower irá colocar as dependências?

Tags: bower

Eu instalei aqui na minha máquina o `bower` globalmente.

```
npm install -g bower
```

Daí quando eu uso o comando `bower install jquery`, ele instala ele na pasta chamada `bower_components`.

Há alguma maneira de fazer com que o `bower` instale num diretório específico?

Quero instalar justamente no diretório `public/js/` do meu projeto.

Comment: tu tentou criar o .bowerrc e setar o diretório?

Comment: Não ainda, vou tentar agora que me falou. Na verdade, é a primeira vez que mexo com `bower`;

Comment: Dá uma olhadinha aqui http://bower.io/docs/config/, acredito que resolva teu problema

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `--config.cwd=[path]`, exemplo:

```
bower install jquery --config.cwd=/home/brunorb/test
# /home/brunorb/test/bower_components/jquery/
```

Note que ele ainda cria a pasta `bower_components` dentro do dir especificado.

Outra opção é utilizar um arquivo `.bowerrc` e definir o dir na key `directory` como mostrado [aqui](http://bower.io/docs/config/#bowerrc-specification).

Answer (score 3):

Crie um arquivo dentro da raiz do projeto chamado `.bowerrc` com o seguinte conteúdo:

```
{
  "directory": "/novo/local/das/dependencias"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Eu creio que as formas apresentadas acima são boas, mas se você tem a necessidade de gerenciar suas dependências especificando as pastas, porém cada uma delas ficando em uma pasta específica de acordo com o tipo do script (css em uma pasta, e javascript em outra), você pode usar o `bower-installer`.

Para instalá-lo você simplesmente roda:

```
npm install -g bower-installer
```

Após isso, você deve definir no `bower.json`, o valor `"path"` dentro de `install`, especificando as pastas de instalação de cada extensão de arquivo.

Veja:

```
{
  "name" : "test",
  "version": "0.1",
  "dependencies" : {
    "jquery-ui" : "latest"
  },
  "install" : {
    "path" : {
      "css": "minha_pasta_personalizada/arquivos_css",
      "js": "minha_pasta_personalizada/arquivos_js"
    },
    "sources" : {
      "jquery-ui" : [
        "components/jquery-ui/ui/jquery-ui.custom.js",
        "components/jquery-ui/themes/start/jquery-ui.css"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

O atribuito `"sources"` define quais são os arquivos você deseja instalar nos diretórios especificados.

Então, depois dessa definição, basta rodar o comando:

```
 bower-installer
```

Eu estou utilizando ele e acho que é bem eficiente.

Comment: Interessante, não conhecia. Só que isto parece trazer um problema: caso a estrutura interna de paths do projeto especificado mude em um novo release você fica obrigado a corrigir seu bower.json para refletir ela. Normalmente a mudança já faria você ter que mudar os imports no seu HTML de qualquer maneira, contudo assim você tem que alterar o HTML e o .bower.json, uma coisa a mais para manter. Ainda assim muito útil caso por algum motivo você precise de paths específicos.