# Arquivos CSS e JS no Laravel

Tags: laravel, bower

Por "padrão", os arquivos CSS e JS no Laravel ficam na pasta `public`. Porém quando vou criar as dependências com Bower, ele cria a pasta componentes na pasta `vendor`.

Posso trocar a pasta de `vendor` para `public`?

Comment: Tá errado. O `bower` deveria criar na raiz da aplicação  uma pasta chamada `bower_componentes`. Se ele está criando dentro de `vendor`, há alguma coisa errada.

Comment: Então, ele cria na raiz mesmo .. eu me expressei mal @WallaceMaxters!
Eu quis dizer que se eu colocar para criar na pasta public é errado ... porém agora estou confuso pois alguns tutoriais falam para colocar o CSS e JS na pasta resources.

Comment: Colocar na pasta `resources` é para outra coisa. É quando você vai trabalhar com o Laravel Elixir que você bota os assets lá. Se for trabalhar com o desenvolvimento web, sem depender de ferramentas como `gulp` ou `nodejs`, aí você pode usar apenas o `bower` instalando na pasta public.

Comment: Então, eu gostaria de criar as dependências com bower e depois utilizar o gulp como automatizador, é possível ?

Desculpe a ignorância, é que estou aprendendo laravel agora ...

Comment: É melhor você usar o `npm`. O `elixir` do Laravel usa `gulp` para gerenciar as tarefas. Vou te passar um link interessante (é inglês, mas dá pra entender só olhando o código)

Comment: Veja como usar o [elixir](https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5/episodes/10)

Comment: Obrigado! Irei assistir ..
Tem skype ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Talvez o problema esteja na pasta que você está instalando. Se você estiver dentro da pasta `vendor` do seu projeto e rodar o comando `bower install jquery`, ele vai instalar dentro da pasta `vendor`.

A estrutura correta do Laravel (se estivermos falando do Laravel 5), é essa:

```
my_app/
  app
  bootstrap
  resources
  storage
  public
  vendor
```

Assim, você deve instalar com `bower` a partir da pasta `my_app`.

Assim:

```
cd my_app

bower install jquery
```

Também é possível configurar o `bower` para instalar diretamente na pasta `public`.

Veja:

- [Como especificar diretório onde o bower irá colocar as dependências?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/111470/como-especificar-diret%C3%B3rio-onde-o-bower-ir%C3%A1-colocar-as-depend%C3%AAncias)

## Complemento

Na minha humilde opinião, sugiro que você utilize o `Laravel Elixir`. Ele usa o `gulp` para automatizar tarefas, como minificação de assets, unificação e até compilação de `less` ou `coffescript`.

Algumas fontes:

- https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5/episodes/10
- https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/elixir

Com ele, você poderia, por exemplo, instalar várias dependências para seu projeto, como por exemplo, jQuery, jQuery-UI e Bootstrap e, em seguida, compilar os scripts para um arquivo só. Isso é muito útil!

## Pequeno exemplo com Laravel Elixir

Você pode instalar algumas bibliotecas via `bower` e utilizar o `elixir`. Eu recomendo que você crie o arquivo `.bowerrc` para configurar o  diretório onde vai instalar os componentes do `bower`.

Faça algo parecido com:

```
{
  "directory" : "resources/assets"
}
```

Eu usei a pasta `resources/assets` pois é de onde o Laravel Elixir lê os arquivos de assets para gerar assets para rodar em produção (unidos ou minificados, por exemplo).

Em seguida, você pode rodar, por exemplo, `bower install jquery`. Os arquivo serão instalados na pasta `resource/assets/jquery`.

Agora utilize o `elixir`, dentro do arquivo `gulpfile.js`, para poder copiar, versionar, minificar ou unir os arquivos da sua aplicação. Por exemplo:

```
elixir(function (mix) {
    // 'scripts' aponta para resources/assets/js por padrão
    mix.scripts([
        "../jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
        "../outra_library/lib.js"
    ], "public/js/vendor.js")
});
```

Após essa definição, você pode rodar o comando `gulp`, que fará com que seus arquivos sejam compilados para `public/js/vendor.js`. Então basta você incluir esse arquivo no seu template principal.

Comment: Melhor explicação impossível hahahahah !